# No output to log from tee when starting mplayer as an arg to gnome-terminal

Tags: io-redirection, mplayer, gnome-terminal

I want to view mplayer's normal terminal output, and also write it to a log.
That works fine when I run mplayer from the commandline, eg:

```
mplayer "$HOME/gdr01.wav" 2>&1 |tee $HOME/junk.log
```

However, I want to launch mplayer in it's own gnome-terminal window. Neither of the following commands write to the log, althought the terminal display works.

```
(gnome-terminal -e "mplayer $HOME/gdr01.wav 2>&1 |tee $HOME/junk.log" &)
 gnome-terminal -e "mplayer $HOME/gdr01.wav 2>&1 |tee $HOME/junk.log" &
```

What is at play here, and what is the trick to get it to work?

*EDIT:*  The problem is that I get the *terminal's* mesages being written to the log (eg. an `ibus` warning). However, although *mplayer* generates thousands of lines, none are written to the log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's going on is that gnome-terminal's command line parsing is funky. You're running `mplayer` with  `/home/ferer/gdr01.wav`, `2>&1`, `|tee` and `/home/ferer/junk.log` as arguments. If you wait for the end of the audio file, you'll see error messages about these nonexistent files for a microsecond before the terminal closes.

Either figure out gnome-terminal's intricate rule. Or, what I recommend: yse the `-x` option instead of `-e` and invoke a shell explicitly.

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'mplayer "$HOME/gdr01.wav" 2>&1 |tee $HOME/junk.log'
```

Comment: *@Gilles:* Thanks.. This is still a fuzzy issue to me, but I haven't noticed any discernable difference in how -x vs -e work, other than the quoting syntax. However, in the last hour, I stumbled on the same shell method you've suggested, when I recalled noticing that when mplayer is run directly from the CLI, its parent is `bash`, but when launched as an arg to `gnome-terminal` its parent is `gnome-terminal`... so I added 'bash -c' and it worked.. I don't quite understand why.. Is it that this immediate parent layer is needed to handle the io-redirection? I suppose it is...

Comment: @ferer With `-e`, `gnome-terminal` does its own vaguely shell-like parsing of the argument (in simple cases, it splits at spaces, but that's not all it does) but does not actually invoke a shell. With `-x`, `gnome-terminal` invokes the given program with exactly the given arguments.

Comment: (a general note to readers).. Just so that I won't have to export my vars (other than known environment vars like $HOME, which are already "exported"), I've used a variant of Gilles' command; here it is: `gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'mplayer "$1" 2>&1 |tee "$2"' 0 "$aud" "$log"` ... The `0` is just a placeholder for what typically is `$0`. The two args which follow the `0` are $1 and $2 ..(the `0` can be whatever you like)...

Answer (score 0):

```
gnome-terminal -x mplayer $HOME/gdr01.wav 2>&1 |tee $HOME/junk.log &
```

This command at least creates the log file.

Comment: Your command behaves exactly the same as mine (`-x` vs `-e`). The problem is that it produces a log of the **terminal's** output, but **not** of what `mplayer` outputs..  It gives **1** line in the log (an `ibus` warning).  This same message appears in the log even when not launching `mplayer`, eg. `gnome-terminal  2>&1 |tee $HOME/junk.log &`  ... mplayer's output is thousands of lines long (although it appears on screen as a recurring overlaid line); it generates approximately 4-5 lines per second, but they don't end up in the log.

Answer (score -1):

I would try to put `exec` in front of `mplayer`, since it is running it on a different shell.